# How can I disable the left column in plone4 on all pages?

Tags: plone

I'd like to have a 2/3:1/3 layout for my website.

I found the statment "disable_column_one python:request.set('disable_plone.leftcolumn',1)" on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872306/how-can-i-remove-portlets-in-edit-mode-with-plone-4) site, but I don't know where to apply it (or how in the main template).

@aclark With 2/3:1/3 i intend a content column with 66% width and a right-slot column with 33% width.

Comment: What is a 2/3:1/3 layout? And how does disabling column one help achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you might just try removing/hiding all the left column portlets in your site/@@manage-portlets and see if that gets you what you want.  If it does and you don't have site contributors that will mess up your layout by adding left portlets, then that will be best as it involves no customizations.

Otherwise, if you want to use the approach given in that link, you'll need to make sure the tal:define="..." provided by David is executed for every page on which you want the column to be disabled.  So if you want it disabled on every page in the site, then you'll need to customize main_template and put that tal:define in a top level element that contains all the other elements, say the  element.  :-)

BTW, if your customizing main_template, you can't use the metal:fill-slot David suggests as that slot is *defined* in main_template.

Answer (score 1):

You will find all the main_template  inside the portal_skins with tab Find

```
<tal:block tal:define="foo python:request.set('disable_plone.leftcolumn', 1)"/>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

..