# Can I enable users on Plone4 to show/hide the Portlet column on-the-fly

Tags: plone

The Portlets in Plone are quite handy but I'd like to be able to provide some method to users to be able to temporarily hide/show the portlets column.  That is, by clicking a button, the portlets column should collapse and you see the content page in full width. Then clicking again and the portlets panel on the left expands and the main content page width shrinks to accommodate.

I've observed the HTML ID of the portlets column is "portal-column-one" and I tried adding a button to the page that runs javascript to set the visibility property of that element to "hidden" but this seemed to have no effect.  I was able to go into Firebug and add style="visibility:hidden;" to the "portal-column-one" element and it had the effect of making the region invisible w/o resizing the page.

I am using Plone 4.1.  I have the site configured with navigation portlet on all pages except the main page which has Navigation, Review List and Recent Changes.

So it seems it must be possible to embed some javascript in the page (I was thinking of adding this to the plone.logo page which I've already customized).  But I guess its more complicated than the few stabs I've made at it.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

## Solution (Thanks to input from Ulrich Schwarz and hvelarde):

The solution I arrived at uses JavaScript to set CSS attributes to show/hide the Portlets Column (Left side) and expand the content column to fill the space the porlets column filled.

I started by customizing the Plone header template to add a link for the user to toggle the view of the Porlets column.  I also put the necessary javascript functions in this header.

To customize the header, go to the following page (need to be logged in as Admin of your Plone site):

http://SERVER/SITE/portal_view_customizations/zope.interface.interface-plone.logo

Where:

- SERVER is the address and port of your site (e.g. localhost:8080)
- SITE is the short name of your Plone Site

To create this page:

1. Go to Site Setup (as Admin)
2. Go to Zope Management Interface
3. Click on "portal_view_customizations"
4. Click on "plone.logo" (or at least this is where I choose to put the button so it would be located just above the navigation Portlet)
5. Add the following to the page:

---

```
<script>
function getById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function TogglePortletsPanel() {
  var dispVal = getById('portal-column-one').style.display
  if( dispVal == "none") { // Normal display
    SetPortletsPanelState("inline");
  } else { // Full Screen Content
    SetPortletsPanelState("none");
  }
}
function SetPortletsPanelState(dispVal) {
  var nav = getById('portal-column-one');
  var content = getById('portal-column-content');
  if( dispVal == "none") { // Normal display
    nav.style.display='none';
    content.className='cell width-full position-0';
    // Set cookie to updated value
    setCookie("portletDisplayState","none",365);
  } else { // Full Screen Content
    nav.style.display='inline';
    content.className='cell width-3:4 position-1:4';
    // Set cookie to updated value
    setCookie("portletDisplayState","inline",365);
  }
}
function InitializePortletsPanelState() {
  var portletDisplayState=getCookie("portletDisplayState");
//alert("portletDisplayState="+portletDisplayState)
  if (portletDisplayState!=null) SetPortletsPanelState(portletDisplayState);
}
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
//alert(c_name+"="+value);
// cookie format: document.cookie = 'name=value; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var exp= ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + escape(value) + exp + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name)  return unescape(y);
  }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {oldonload(); }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(InitializePortletsPanelState);

</script>
<a style="font-size:50%;" href="javascript:TogglePortletsPanel();">Toggle Portlets Panel</a>
```

6. Save the page

Notes:

- I got the names of the plone div elements using Firebug.
- I also used Firebug to experiment with different settings to speed up prototyping.  For example, editing the HTML inline to verify settings do as expected.
- There is a slight but of delay until the Left Portlet panel is hidden.  This is only obvious on Safari for me (which is probably due to how fast it is) but not on Firefox or IE.

Comment: Take a look at David Glick's answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872306/how-can-i-remove-portlets-in-edit-mode-with-plone-4

Comment: Seems David Glick's answer may be the approach I want.  

Does this approach allow for the setting for showing or hiding the left panel via URL Params or something?  I don't quite follow what is meant by "setting a couple variables on the request" in that answer.   
The goal is to allow the user to remove the navigation panel, browse but then be able to restore it.

Comment: I think you could use some JavaScript code to set a cookie storing the user's preference.

Comment: Thanks!! Good idea.  I'll try that as soon as I get some time and update this thread with the full details of the working solution.

Comment: @hvelarde - As I commented below, I implemented the solution to store cookies and restore with the onload event.  It works but there is a noticeable UI change upon loading the page - not very elegant.  Do you understand how David Glick's answer works?  Is it suggesting that you can pass some URL Param in the request for a page and Plone will render that page with or without the navigation portlet depending on the value of the url parameter?  That would be ideal (though I'm not sure how to modify all links in the page to enable this).  Arghh!  This should really be a standard feature of Plone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just a matter of setting the right property: you want `display:none`, not `visibility:hidden`.

But even then, the content area will probably not reflow automatically, you'll need to (dynamically) change the class on it as well.
Specifically, you'll need to put classes `width-full` and `position-0` on `portal-column-content`, instead of `width-1:2` and `position-1:4`.

Comment: I guess I had not thought thru the CSS solution well enough :)    I was able to get this work with Ulrich's suggestions but realize that once you navigate to a new page the settings are lost and the navbar returns.

Comment: @Steve: If you want to continue hacking along those lines: you can access the cookie client-side with javascript and store a flag there.
(This will have caching advantages over having the flag serverside.)

Comment: I was able to get this to work but the downside is there is a visible time when the left portlets panel is visible and then collapsed once the onload event triggers.  Pretty kludgy.  I'm going to explore more the answer by David Glick that hvelarde referred to.

Comment: I modified my solution a bit more and now everything works just fine. I'm able to toggle the Portlet Panel and as the page renders use the set cookie to show or hide the panel.   I must have had things wrong before because now the portlet panel does not show upon page loading (on FireFox and IE anyway - on Safari it shows up only very briefly and is bearable).  I'll try to document my full solution in a new answer since comments are limited in size.

Comment: I noticed that you have solved your problem; I thing it would be better that you write the solution separated from the question, as an answer, because it is an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This must be achieved client side by javascript (jquery).

You must first read documentation about the css grid framework used by plone: deco.gs. The website is down so, git clone this repo: https://github.com/limi/deco.gs and open pages in a webbrowser

Note: you just have to change css classes on the containers.

Comment: I think this may be a little high of a learning curve for me.  If I invested the time, would this solution avoid the issue I'm finding with hand-written Javascript and cookies where the page noticably collapses the portlets panel after loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try [adi.fullscreen](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/adi.fullscreen), it respects Plone's css-structure as Ulrich Schwarz thoughtfully mentioned.

Comment: adi.fullscreen works in the same way as the solution proposed by Ulrich - setting are lost upon navigating to the next page.<br/> I'm hoping to find a way to make the change to the layout stick from page to page until the user chooses to reset normal view.

Comment: btw: Did you write this Plone addon upon seeing this post?  I noticed the date on the pypi page was same date as your post.

Comment: Actually yes ;) I thought often this is a common and nice feature would be a nice feature and a lot of people requested it, but never had the time really. Something positive about winter time...